# Click event only works on the first page of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a paginated table using tablesorter.js. There are links in the table, each with class `gl_link`. Now, I have added an event to all links using jQuery, with:

```
$('.gl_link').click(function(){
       alert(this.id); 
    });
```

On the first page of the paginated table, this works fine, but when I move on to other pages nothing happens when I click the links.

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pzuek/

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the elements are generated dynamically, you should delegate the event:

```
$('#list_table').delegate('.gl_link', 'click', function(){
   alert(this.id); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6Feu/

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.7+, use the `on()` function instead: `$('#list_table').on('click', '.gl_link', function(){ alert(this.id); });`

Comment: @Mottie Yes, I should have mentioned that. He/she is using jQuery 1.6, that's why I had used `delegate`.

Comment: No worries, just trying to help out :P